# Camera view with runtime overlay in Appcelerator/Phonegap? Possible?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, appcelerator, augmented-reality

Is it possible to create a camera view, which I can overlay at runtime with some text (as the user points the camera to certain objects) ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Phonegap but with Titanium you can open a camera view by executing Ti.Media.showCamera(options [obj]).

Within the options parameter object you can specify an overlay view.

More information found [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/CameraOptionsType-object.html).